# How to change contours in different axises in the presence of a 3-D object

Tags: matlab

I have a 3-D object which I have plotted it on MATLAB. I am also plotting 4 different 2-D planes using `quiver3(a,-Y1,X1,b,V1,U1)` in the same figure. Now the question is how can I move those 2-D planes in the figure in y plane without moving the 3-D object?

I know it is a quiet simple question and It would be just tricky, but I could.t find it anyways.

Comment: What do you mean by "move the planes in the figure y plane"? you mean quiver(a,-Y1+3,X1,b,V1,U1)?

Comment: When plotting u can usually get the plot object like `p = plot(...)` there you can change the data `set(p,'XData',[1,2])`. This should work with `quiver` too.

Comment: sorry I meant y axis! thank you guys it worked :)